# Rails - Basic model conventions and basic association confusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My understanding of the conventions I'm currently dealing with is as follows:

Model names should be in TitleCaps.

Variable names should be lower_cased_and_under_scored.

Associations should be to the singular version of the foreign table name with _id appended, e.g. user_uploaded_picture_id

- When doing "rails generate model ModelName" - should it be in TitleCaps at that point?
- Should every database table I need have every association specified? On this note, do associations both ways need to be specified, i.e. should every has_one/has_many be matched to a belongs_to?
- Should there be a model for every database table I intend to create?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple questions in one :)

1. Both `model_name` and `ModelName` are accepted and generates the correct model and table names.
2. You don't need to specify every associations only those which you want to use.
3. No, you don't need to create a model for every table. But if you'll use that table from Rails it's easier to have one.